# Concat line with next line if both contain the same number of a specified character

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, perl

I need to `concat` lines which contains a specified number of the specified character. I don't have any idea, it's easy in `python` or `ruby`, but I want to do this using `perl` / `sed` / `awk` / `bash`, without using any loops or `uniq -c`. I need calc how many `plus` characters contains line and `concat` with next if contains the same number of characters

```
a+a
a+a
a+a+a
a+a+a
a+a+a+a
a+a+a+a
```

Output should be:

```
a+a + a+a
a+a+a + a+a+a
a+a+a+a + a+a+a+a
```

Comment: Could be any number of characters, or just the max 4 in your example?

Comment: Many and many... can have more than 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F "+" 'NR%2{nf=NF;l=$0;next}{sep=(nf==NF?" + ":RS);printf "%s%s%s\n",l,sep,$0}' file
```

For a line by line analysis, let's unwind it:

```
awk -F "+" '
  NR%2{nf=NF;l=$0;next}
  {
    sep=(nf==NF?" + ":RS)
    printf "%s%s%s\n",l,sep,$0
  }
' file
```

- Set field separator to `+`.
- If the line number is odd (`NR%2`), get the number of fields into `nf` and the whole record into `l`.
- Else,

  - If the number of fields of this line is equal to the number of fields of the previous line, set `sep=" + "`. Else, set `sep=RS` (`RS`, the record separator, is the newline character).
  - Print `l`, `sep`, `$0`, and a newline character.